# Does eclipse on windows add Control M characters

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to determine if Eclipse on Windows add control-M characters. I have not seen any setting for it in Preferences->Text Editors.
If I don't see Control M characters using vi -b  on Linux, can I conclude that control-M characters are not present when using eclipse on Windows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally found under `Window > Preferences > General > Workspace` the next text file line delimiter preference. Default is the delimiter of the OS you are using Eclipse on, but you can change that.

[image: Preference for text file line delimiter]

That means that when you now change a file (coming from Linux) under Windows, and you have not changed the default, the line end convention (of the existing file) will be kept (`New text file line delimiter`), but if you create a new file, the convention of your current OS (Windows) will be used.

Comment: I'm still getting them. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 11):

You can change line delimiters for all existing files for a project by selecting the project and got to File-->Convert Line Delimiters To-->Unix.

This will modify line delimiter for all files under the project. This will solve the issue.

Comment: This is a great way to fix messed up files!